# rails bootstrap and aligning checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to horizontally align a checkbox and it's label in Rails.  I'm using bootstrap as well.  any help is appreciated.

```
    <p>
      <%= label_tag(:relo, "Willing to relocate:", class: "checkbox") %>
      <%= check_box_tag :relo, value = "true", checked = false, class: "" %>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical-align sometimes will require two inline elements next to each other to function correctly.

'nowrap' means that the whole label text always stays next to the checkbox.

in your css file...

```
.checkboxes label {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 padding-right: 10px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }

.checkboxes input {
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

.checkboxes label span {
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

in your view...

```
<form>
  <div class="checkboxes">
     <label for="x"><input type="checkbox" id="x" /> <span>Label text      x</span></label>
    <label for="y"><input type="checkbox" id="y" /> <span>Label text y</span></label>
    <label for="z"><input type="checkbox" id="z" /> <span>Label text z</span></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't rails it's just HTML.  The question is how to get a checkbox in a rails app to align with the label.